# I want to conversion cm per 300px

Tags: javascript

Now in javascript...

I'm trying to pixel to cm.

I want to show cm per 300pixel.

> means if 300pixel = 1cm
>
> ```
>   else if 600pixel = 2cm
> ```

how to make it dynamically?

thanks.....

Comment: `cm = pixel/300.0` or `pixel = cm*300`

Comment: Umh... should this be moved to [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) ; ) ?

Comment: @Teemu ah ha! yep... I just knew that site!